# Send email via Exchange Web Services (EWS)

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to send an email through exchange server using Exchange Web Services (EWS). 
I've configured some parameters but it can't send.
I've tried other methods, like third party assemblies, and with that is possible to send, because of that I think I've missed some parameters or method to configure my connection.

I hope you can help me.

I've pasted some code below ...

```
        Try
            Dim vFrom As String = "mail@domain.exchange.com"
            Dim vTo As String = "personal@mydomain.es" 
            Dim vSubject As String = "Test " & DateTime.Now.ToString
            Dim vBody As String = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ..."
            Dim vHost As String = "webmail.domain.exchange.com"
            Dim vUsr As String = "boss@mydomain.es"
            Dim vPsw As String = "1234567890" 

            Dim service As New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1)
            service.Credentials = New WebCredentials(vUsr, vPsw, vHost)
            service.Url = New System.Uri("https://" & vHost)

            Dim mail As New EmailMessage(service)
            mail.From = vFrom
            mail.ToRecipients.Add("John", vTo)
            mail.Subject = vSubject
            mail.Body = vBody
            mail.SendAndSaveCopy()

        Catch ex As ServiceRequestException
            MsgBox(ex.Message + " - sendMailExchange(ServiceRequestException)")
        Catch ex As WebException
            MsgBox(ex.Message + " - sendMailExchange(WebException)")
            'Catch ex As SmtpException
            '    MsgBox(ex.Message + " - sendMailExchange(SmtpException)")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message + " - sendMailExchange(Exception)")
        End Try
```

Thanks for help...

Comment: Why doesnt it work?  errors?

Comment: It sends a 401 error "not authorized", but with dll (EASendMail45 on try period) it send the mail successful

Comment: Thanks dude - Always post as much error info as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old thread ... but since I had a similar problem today for which I found the solution I thought I would let you know ...

The issue is the URI you are using. Instead of "https://webmail.domain.exchange.com" you should try "https://webmail.domain.exchange.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"

Comment: Link only answers do not work well here, when the link dies the answer is without value.  see {Referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) for improving your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the additional info.  With it I was able to identify someone with the same issue.

Have a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13517513/2319909

It appears that your username variable for the `WebCredentials` may be wrong.

Comment: I've tried too like : "domain\user" and "user@domain.es" and only "user" because my email domain is different of my domain server... my email is like name@some.domain.es and my domain is only domain.es... I've tried all I could imagine...

Comment: 401 is unauthorized access, so it is permissions.  Sorry cant help more.

Comment: Ok... Thanks!!! I'll try to find some information about this issue with my company's system IT dept.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this against an on-premise Exchange server on your corporate network, try replacing WebCredential with System.Net.NetworkCredential.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to use de NetworkCredential instead of WebCredentials but the results are the same.

I've got the correct server address but now instead of 401 error I get the 405 error (not permitted)

But is unable to send the email.

Someone has something new that I can try? 

Thanks all for your efforts.

Comment: I would recommend downloading EWSEditor from http://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ and checking if it can connect to your server. It could be that there's an issue with how the server's configured.